# Adding restrictions to Google API Key

Tags: google-api, gcloud, google-api-nodejs-client, google-iam

I need to list/change the Google API key restriction by Google API or CI.

I tried to add HTTP referrer restriction to Google API key by Node JS API or gcloud CI, but I only got to list the "service account keys, however I need to list and change the "API keys".
Currently, is possible add restriction by the Google Cloud Console, but like I need to change the API key restriction many times I need to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot; there is no public API for managing API Keys (or OAuth client IDs).

Consider filing a feature request on Google's public issue tracker ([link](https://issuetracker.google.com))

Comment: Thank you for tip